# Microsoft Word, empty space which cannot remove

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

I have an empty space I cannot remove.

[image: Picture with the problem]

there are two signs, marked with a circle which are probably the cause of the problem, but cannot find information what is that and how to remove it.

Thanks for help in advance!

Answer (score 4):

#### There are two signs, marked with a circle

It's a non-printing character (**Cell marker**).

---

#### What are Cell markers?

> In tables you will see one additional character, the universal
>   monetary symbol `¤`, which displays variously at various point sizes
>   and magnifications but upon close inspection is seen to be a circle
>   with four lines radiating from the corners.
>
> This is the end-of-cell marker. It is a little like the paragraph mark
>   in that it contains paragraph formatting for the last (or only)
>   paragraph in the cell, but it also holds formatting for the cell.
>
> The same mark at the end of each row is the (wait for it) end-of-row
>   marker, which serves a similar purpose with regard to row formatting.

---

#### How do I turn of the display of non-printing characters?

> By default, the Formatting toolbar in Word has a button with the ¶
>   icon. If you hover your mouse over it, the ScreenTip says “Show/Hide
>   ¶.” (In Word 2007 this button is in the Paragraph group on the Home
>   tab.)
>
> [image]

Source [What do all those funny marks, like the dots between the words in my document, and the square bullets in the left margin, mean?](http://word.mvps.org/faqs/formatting/NonPrintChars.htm)